# Differentiating $e^x$ from first principles using limits.

Tags: limits, derivatives, exponential-function, limits-without-lhopital

I have been trying to differentiate the exponential function from first principles without the use of Taylor's series or the derivative of its inverse function ($\frac{d}{dx} (\ln x) = \frac{1}{x}$ and $\ln (e^x) = x$.

Let $f(x) = e^x$, then differentiating $f(x)$ from first principles,
$$f^\prime(x) = \lim_{\delta x \to 0} \frac{f(x+\delta x) - f(x)}{\delta x} = \lim_{\delta x \to 0} \frac{e^{x+\delta x} - e^x}{\delta x} = \lim_{\delta x \to 0}\frac{e^x(e^{\delta x} - 1)}{\delta x} = e^x \lim_{\delta x \to 0} \frac{e^{\delta x} - 1}{\delta x}$$

Therefore, in order to prove from first principles that $\frac{d}{dx}(e^x) = e^x$, I would need to first show that
$$\lim_{\delta x \to 0} \frac{e^{\delta x} - 1}{\delta x} = 1$$

However, I am not sure how to evaluate this limit and the use of L'Hôpital's rule requires preliminary knowledge on the derivative of $e^x$.

Is it possible to prove the derivative of $e^x$ from first principles solely using limits, or is it impossible as the knowledge of its derivative is a prerequisite to its discovery by Bernoulli?

Comment: You should specify which is the definition of $e^x$. The answer can vary.

Comment: What is your definition of $e^x$?

Comment: Yes, most people define the exponential by its power series, so that differentiating its power series is a proof by first principles. Others define it as the inverse function of log, so that that's a proof by first principles. Others still define it as the solution to $y'=y$, so that no proof is required. In any of the above definitions, it's easier to prove that the exponential is its own derivative than it is to prove $e^xe^y=e^{x+y}$, which you have used freely.

Comment: There is also the definition of exponentiation which I think is the most elementary, which proceeds by defining $a^x$ for rational $x$ first in standard manner, and then either defining $a^x$ for real $x$ as supremum of $a^r,r<x$ or as limit of $a^r$ as $r\rightarrow x$.

Comment: I see, so $e^x$'s derivative is based on its definition. However, isn't there a particular way in which the above limit could still be evaluated?

Comment: The derivative is not based on definition. But derivation would depend on what you take as a definition.

Comment: @TeofilAleksandrov  Well... it depends on **which** definition you start with: what are the properties of the exponential you're allowed to use and can take for granted?

Comment: You could probably prove it directly from [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality) and $e^x=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac xn)^n$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As I've said fairly often in the last few days (for some reason), one of my favorite equations is:
$$e^x\ge x+1$$
The reason, partly, is that it uniquely defines $e$ without calculus. Hint for a proof: use [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality). (By the way, do equations need equals signs? Or is it *equalities* that need equals signs?)

Now, replacing $x$ by $-x$, we get $e^{-x}\ge1-x$, so:
$$e^x\le\frac1{1-x}$$
(The inequality gets reverse for $x>1$, as the right-hand side is negative there. But we only care about when $x$ is near zero.)

Thus:
\begin{align}
x+1\le{}&e^x\le\frac1{1-x}\\
x\le{}&e^x-1\le\frac x{1-x}\\
1\le^*{}&\frac{e^x-1}x\le^*\frac1{1-x}
\end{align}
*Since we just divided by $x$, the inequalities get reversed if $x$ is negative. It doesn't affect the argument.

Let $x$ tend to zero. By the squeeze theorem:
$$1=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1}x$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, this answers my question completely. It is really fascinating how this simple inequality above can simplify and define $e$ without calculus, especially when you compare what you have written to the definition of $e$ as a limit using calculus (http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/ma122/elimit.pdf). Bernoulli's inequality is powerful.

Comment: Just that inequality is not sufficient to define $e^{x}$. It is also important to have the property $f(x)f(y) = f(x + y)$ without which you wont get the second inequality. Also you will need calculus machinery to show that there exists a unique function $f$ with these two properties namely $f(x) \geq 1 + x$ and $f(x)f(y) = f(x + y)$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I'm not trying to define $\exp$, I'm trying to define the number $e$. That other property follows from the laws of exponents. (It's not too hard to define exponentiation with a positive real base and real exponent.)

Comment: ok i got it... I was thinking about your approach to real exponents and guessed that you are using the inequality to define $e^{x}$. now its ok. anyway I have already upvoted this nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I guess I will post an answer instead. I hope its not inappropriate.

As indicated by the comments, the answer varies on your definition of $e^x$. In fact one definition is implicitly by:

$$ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{e^h - 1}{h} = 1$$

Defining $e^x$ this way, you are finished. If you define it as

$$ e^x = \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^n$$

you are left with a bit more work.

Regardless, you will probably find all the answers you're looking for in the following thread: [Proof of derivative of $e^x$ is $e^x$ without using chain rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/199447/proof-of-derivative-of-ex-is-ex-without-using-chain-rule)

Comment: $e^x$ is _not_ the unique function satisfying this property. $x+1$ is another one.

Comment: @Wojowu I think that he meant $\exp$ is the only function with $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\exp(h)-1}h=1$ and $\exp(a)\exp(b)=\exp(a+b)$.

Comment: @Wojowu You're right. Corrected.