# Show that $f'(0)= \lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\frac{f(\Delta x)-1}{\Delta x} = 1$

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, complex-numbers, exponential-function, epsilon-delta

This question is related to another question I asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1668026/proof-of-existence-and-uniqueness-of-the-exponential-function-using-odes).

Specifically, using the definition of $e$ I gave in that question:

> There exists a unique complex function $f$ such that
>
> 1. $f(z)$ is a single valued function $f(z) \in \mathbb{R}$ whenever $z \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f(1) = e$
> 2. $\forall z_{1}, z_{2} \in \mathbb{C}$, $f$ satisfies $f(z_{1} + z_{2}) = f(z_{1})f(z_{2})$
> 3. $f$ is complex differentiable for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

Essentially, what I'm doing in the problem linked here is trying to prove that for $f$ such a function as meets those three criteria, $f^{\prime}(0) = 1$. The $f$ I am hoping to get eventually is $f(z) = e^{z}$, but that is what I am trying to prove; I cannot use anything specifically about $e^{z}$ here, only what is provided here in our definition of the function $f$.

Eventually, I was able to show that $f^{\prime}(0) = \lim_{\Delta z \to 0} \frac{f(\Delta z)-f(0)}{\Delta z} = f(0) \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{f(\Delta x) - 1}{\Delta x}$.

But, I don't know how to go any further!

I need to show that $f'(0) = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{f(\Delta x)-1}{\Delta x} = 1$.

Other people have posted similar questions to this on here, but they haven't been answered particularly well. I can't assume anything about $e^z$, nor can I use anything like L'Hopital's rule, or logarithms, or series expansions.

This is probably very very simple. Even an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof would be good, if you could write the whole thing out. I tried that route and I wasn't able to make any progress.

Please help!!

Comment: @Dr.MV, I don't have $e^{z}$ available to me right now. Right now, I have a function $f$ that meets the above criteria. I am trying to prove that that function $f$ is in fact $e^{z}$ using the differential equations method of proof. In order to do that, the first step I need to take is to show that $f^{\prime}(0) = 1$. What I have posted in this question here is the very last part of showing that, but I don't know how to finish it.

Comment: What definition of $e$ are you using?

Comment: This might help: You could first define  $e^z $ as this unique function fulfilling all your criteria and then assume there is another function. 
You could define: $g(z) = f(z)e^{-z} $ with  $f(0) = 1 $ and $f(z) = f'(z)$ 
Observe: $g'(z)$ is constant, then you would be almost done.

Comment: @Imago. no that's showing uniqueness. First, I have to show existence.

Comment: @DanielFischer, see above.

Comment: @DanielFischer, I am trying to prove the existence of a function fulfilling all the three properties of $e^{z}$ listed above. The first step of this process is to prove that $f^{\prime}(0)=1$ for our candidate function $f$, and I cannot assume anything about $e$ other than the three properties listed above.

Comment: The question asked by @DanielFischer is prompted by the defining criterion $f(1)=e$.  So, what is $e$ here?  If not, then it is a completely arbitrary piece of information.

Comment: I'm not asking about the exponential function, just the definition of the number $e$. Without a definition, the property $f(1) = e$ makes no sense. By far the easiest way to show existence would be to write down the Taylor series and obtain all properties from that. For what reason do you forbid series expansions? Is that explicitly ruled out in the exercise? What alternative ways of showing existence of functions with given properties are available?

Comment: @DanielFischer, I suppose it's approximately equal to 2.7. We cannot use series expansions because we don't have a function to expand! Just using those three properties, and anything immediately obtainable from them, I am supposed to show that that limit = 1.

Comment: You need some exact definition of $e$, otherwise $f(1) = e$ is meaningless. The functions satisfying 2. and 3. are the constant $f \equiv 0$, and the functions $f(z) = \exp (a\cdot z)$ for some $a\in \mathbb{C}$. If we take $f(\mathbb{R}) \subset \mathbb{R}$ into consideration, the possibilities reduce to $0$ or $\exp (a\cdot z)$ with $a\in \mathbb{R}$. The latter clearly has $f'(0) = a$. Without an exact definition of $e$, it is thus flat-out impossible to deduce $f'(0) = 1$.

Comment: @DanielFischer, I figured it out! I'm allowed to assume the real-valued function $e^{x}$ exists, and its derivative at $0$ is equal to $1$!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that we have

$$f(z_1+z_2)=f(z_1)f(z_2) \tag 1$$

and $f(1)=e$.

Then, from $(1)$ we see that $f(0+1)=f(1)=f(0)f(1)\implies f(0)=1$.

Next, we analyze the derivative of $f(z)$ and find that

$$\begin{align}
f'(z)&=\lim_{\Delta z\to 0}\frac{f(z+\Delta z)-f(z)}{\Delta z}\\\\
&=\lim_{\Delta z\to 0}\frac{f(z)f(\Delta z)-f(z)}{\Delta z}\\\\
\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}&=\lim_{\Delta z\to 0}\frac{f(\Delta z)-1}{\Delta z}\\\\
&=f'(0)\tag 1
\end{align}$$

Note that $(1)$ hold for all $z$.  In particular, it holds for real values of $z$, say $x$.  Then, we have

$$f'(x)=f'(0)f(x)\tag 2$$

and $f(1)=e$.

The solution to $(2)$ is $f(x)=Ce^{f'(0)x}$.

Since $f(0)=1$, then $C=1$.  And since $f(1)=e$, $f'(0)=1$.

And we are done!

Comment: What if we had something different, say $f(1)=0$?

Comment: @simpleart Art.  The answer would be different in that case.  In fact, it would be $0$.

Comment: I would like to see the solution for $f(1)=a$ in terms of $a$.

Comment: @simpleart $f'(0)=\log(a)$ for real values of $a>0$.  So, $f(x)=a^x$.

Comment: Oh, what I nice and simple solution.  :)  thanks.

Comment: @SimpleArt  Art.  Sure.  You're welcome.  My pleasure.  - Mark

Comment: You assume that the solution to $f'(x) = kf(x)$ is $f(x) = ce{kx}$. But this assumption is not trivial one. It requires us to introduce the number $e$ and the exponential function $e^{x}$ in a well defined manner. I have tried to take a different approach which assumes minimal stuff.

Comment: @Dr.MV Lovely, concise answer. Enjoyed that. +1

Comment: @bacon Thank you.  Much appreciative!

Comment: @paramanandsingh Yes, but the OP made clear that for real argument, one could assume that the exponential function's properties were known.  ;-) ... Mark

Comment: Agreed! And +1. I checked OP's comments to his question a bit late.

Answer (score 4):

I spent enough time reading this question and the linked question where you sort of try to define $e$. **To be very clear none of your questions have defined $e$**.

Restricting first to the case of real variables only I want to shed some light here. One of the reasons you are having trouble trying to prove $f'(0) = 1$ is because you have not given a definition of $e$. Note that the functional equation $$f(x + y) = f(x)f(y)$$ only guarantees that $f(x)$ is differentiable for all $x$ if it is differentiable at a single point $x = 0$ and moreover $f'(x) = f'(0)f(x)$. But the value of $f'(0)$ crucially depends on the value of $f(1)$. In fact we can put this dependence as a function by setting $f(1) = t$ and $f'(0) = g(t)$. It can be proved with some effort that $g(1) = 0$ and $g'(t) = 1/t$ for all $t > 0$.

---

**Theorem:** *Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function with the property that $f(x + y) = f(x)f(y)$ and let $f'(0)$ exist and let $f(1) = t\neq 0$. Then value of $f'(0)$ is a function of $t$ (say $f'(0) = g(t)$) with the following properties $$g(1) = 0, g'(t) = \frac{1}{t}$$*

**Proof:** In the above I have set $f(1) = t$ and assumed that $t \neq 0$. This is because if $f$ vanishes at any point (say $f(a) = 0$) then by functional equation $f(x) = f(x - a)f(a) = 0$ and so the function is identically $0$. So it is essential to have $f(1) = t \neq 0$ (so that the problem is non-trivial and interesting).

Moreover from the existence of $f'(0)$ it is easily possible to deduce that $f'(x)$ exists for all $x$ and $f'(x) = f(x)f'(0)$. Hence it follows that $f(x)$ is continuous and since $f$ is non-zero at any point, it follows by intermediate value theorem that $f(x)$ is of constant sign (namely the sign of $f(1) = t$). If $f(1) = t$ is negative then $f(2) = f(1)f(1) = t^{2} > 0$ and hence $f$ changes sign. This is not possible and hence we conclude that $f(1) = t > 0$ and hence $f(x) > 0$ for all $x$. It is now clear that $f(0) = f(0)f(0)$ so that $f(0) = 1$.

Note further that the functional equation also allows us to prove that $f(x) = \{f(1)\}^{x} = t^{x}$ where $x$ is rational and this shows clear dependence of the function $f$ on parameter $t$. Hence it makes sense to change the notation a bit and replace $f$ by $f_{t}$ and thus we have the following properties of $f_{t}$: $$f_{t}(x + y) = f_{t}(x)f_{t}(y), f_{t}(1) = t, f_{t}(0) = 1, f_{t}'(x) = f_{t}'(0)f_{t}(x)\tag{1}$$ To show that the dependence of $f_{t}$ on $t$ is genuine, I show that if $s = t$ then $f_{s} = f_{t}$. Let $h(x) = f_{s}(x)/f_{t}(x)$ and clearly $h(x)$ also satisfies the equation $h(x + y) = h(x)h(y)$ and $h(1) = 1$. As we noted earlier $h(x) = \{h(1)\}^{x} = 1$ when $x$ is rational and hence by continuity $h(x) = 1$ for all $x$ and therefore $f_{s}(x) = f_{t}(x)$ for all $x$.

Further by using $h(x) = f_{st}(x)/f_{s}(x)$ we see that $h(x)$ satisfies the functional equation and $h(1) = t$ so that $h(x) = f_{t}(x)$. Thus we have the following property: $$f_{st}(x) = f_{s}(x)f_{t}(x)\tag{2}$$ for all $x$ and all positive $s, t$.

Next we consider the function $g$ which shows dependence of $f_{t}'(0) = g(t)$ on $f_{t}(1) = t > 0$. We prove that $$g(st) = g(s) + g(t)\tag{3}$$ Clearly we can see that
\begin{align}
g(st) &= f_{st}'(0) = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f_{st}(h) - f_{st}(0)}{h}\notag\\
&= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f_{s}(h)f_{t}(h) - f_{s}(0)f_{t}(0)}{h}\notag\\
&= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f_{s}(h)f_{t}(h) - f_{s}(h)f_{t}(0) + f_{s}(h)f_{t}(0) - f_{s}(0)f_{t}(0)}{h}\notag\\
&= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f_{s}(h)\{f_{t}(h) - f_{t}(0)\} + \{f_{s}(h) - f_{s}(0)\}f_{t}(0)}{h}\notag\\
&= f_{s}(0)f_{t}'(0) + f_{t}(0)f_{s}'(0)\notag\\
&= g(t) + g(s)\notag
\end{align}
Putting $s = t = 1$ we get that $g(1) = 0$. From $(3)$ we also get $g(s) = g((s/t)\cdot t) = g(s/t) + g(t)$ so that $$g(s/t) = g(s) - g(t)\tag{4}$$ We further show that $g(t) > 0$ if $t > 1$ and from $(4)$ this will establish that $g(t)$ is strictly increasing as a function of $t$. For this purpose we use the inequality $$t^{x - 1}(t - 1)\leq \frac{t^{x} - 1}{x} \leq (t - 1)\tag{5}$$ for all rational $x > 0$ and $t > 1$ (for proof of the inequality [see this post](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2014/05/theories-of-exponential-and-logarithmic-functions-part-2_10.html) : equations $(9)$ and following). Translating the above in terms of our function $f_{t}$ we get $$f_{t}(x - 1)(t - 1)\leq \frac{f_{t}(x) - f_{t}(0)}{x} \leq t - 1$$ for all $t > 1$ and all rational $x$. By continuity of $f_{t}$ the same equation holds for all real $x > 0$. Letting $x \to 0^{+}$ we get $$\frac{t - 1}{t} \leq f_{t}'(0) \leq t - 1$$ or $$\frac{t - 1}{t} \leq g(t) \leq t - 1\tag{6}$$ From this equation it follows that $g(t) > 0$ for $t > 1$ and hence $g(t)$ is strictly increasing.

Diving equation $(6)$ by $(t - 1)$ and letting $t \to 1^{+}$ we get via Squeeze theorem $$\lim_{t \to 1^{1+}}\frac{g(t)}{t - 1} = 1$$ It can be easily proved that the same limit holds when $t \to 1^{-}$ by putting $t = 1/s$ and letting $s \to 1^{+}$. Hence $$\lim_{t \to 1}\frac{g(t)}{t - 1} = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{g(1 + h)}{h} = 1\tag{7}$$ It is now easy to prove that $g'(t) = 1/t$. Clearly
\begin{align}
g'(t) &= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{g(t + h) - g(t)}{h}\notag\\
&= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{g((t + h)/t)}{h}\notag\\
&= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{g(1 + (h/t))}{(h/t)}\cdot\frac{1}{t}\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{t}\notag
\end{align}
The proof of the theorem is now complete.

---

We are now in a position to define $e$. Since $g(2) > 0$ and $$g(2^{n}) = ng(2)$$ it follows that $g(2^{n}) \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$ and hence by continuity $g(t)$ takes all possible positive values. By its strictly increasing nature $g$ takes every such value only once. We define $e$ to be the unique positive number such that $g(e) = 1$. Thus if $f(1) = e$ then $f'(0) = 1$. The function $g$ is traditionally denoted by $\log$ or $\ln$. It can also be easily established that the function $g$ is inverse of $f_{e}$.

Comment: Rigorous, lovely! +1

Comment: Well done.  A big +1 ...